# Не работает popup maker

Tags: wordpress, cms, popup, wp-plugin, contact-form7

Необходимо сделать всплывающее окошко с формой через минуту после открытия пользователем сайта. Сама форма реализована на Contact Form 7, в popup maker вставлен шорткод. В предварительном просмотре окошко открывается, на реальной странице - нет. С чем может быть связано?
P. S. Мучаюсь два с половиной часа, такое ощущение, что уже весь интернет перерыл.

Comment: Консоль браузера покажет ошибки js

Comment: @SeVlad, спасибо за ответ, я уже сам разобрался, нужно было после каждого изменения попапа сбрасывать куки